# How can I specify a "where" condition in my query?

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have 2 tables, `Master` and a sub table

Example

Table `Menu`

```
ID         MenuName
---         ------
1            A
2            B 
3            C
4            D
```

Table `MenuType`:

```
Id   MenuID   MenuType
---    ---    -------
1      1       BreakFast
2      1       Lunch
3      1       Dinner 
4      2       Lunch
```

I wanted to select

```
Select MenuName, ID 
from Menu
inner join MenuType on MenuType.MenuID = Menu.id
```

I wanted to fill this as `Menu` object to a checked list box.

My code :

```
Dim ObMenu as List(of Menu)

Dim Query=From un in dbcontest.menuCreations Select Un

ObMenu =Query.ToList
```

How can I specify the `where` condition in this? In normal case we write it as

```
un.MenuType.MenuID = 1
```

but as it's not one to one relation we can write it? So how can I write it?

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that something along these lines should work:

```
Dim Query = (From e inDbContext.MenuCreations
            Where e.MenuId = <whatever>
            Select e).ToList  <or .FirstOrDefault if you are only expecting 1 item to be returned>
```